# Avatar picture is broken

Tags: images, gravatar

I've loaded and reloaded my picture into Gravatar, but it still displays as broken in my admin panel. Also, the email address for my Gravatar account is the same as the email address in my admin profile. It's displayed correctly in the past, so I'm not sure what happened to break it.

Comment: gravatars shouldn't be broken, they should show a default avatar instead, usually the gravatar logo. What does your browsers dev console say? Is the URL a valid URL for the image tag?

Comment: Yes, I agree that they shouldn't be broken and that they should show a default avatar instead. But inside of my admin panel, the avatar shows the "broken image" icon. If I could copy and paste a screen print, I would show you what I mean.

Comment: hmmm have you contacted their support? You didn't answer my other questions about the browser console or the URL. Keep in mind this stack is intended for programming/development questions

Comment: Unfortunately, Gravatar doesn't have any tech support. And their Q&A didn't mention anything about what to do if the Gravatar image breaks. :-(

Comment: what is the gravatar image URL that's broken?

Comment: Hey thanks, Tom. It's the one in my admin panel. Do you have an email I can send you a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshots can be uploaded to the question itself by editing it, but a screenshot would not be helpful here. The broken gravatar is an image tag that has a src URL that is not loading for you for unknown reasons. Knowing that URL would be helpful. I assume you have disabled all plugins and reverted to a default theme, then turned them all back on one by one to see where the cause of the problem is?

Comment: The source url is from Gravatar: https://en.gravatar.com/userimage/16529997/87f7346f48852a6c75f0d07a0494879c.png I was hoping to find another way of locating the source url rather than disabling all of the plugins and reverting to a default theme because I'm really concerned about breaking my site if I do that.

Comment: that URL works for me, no dual agency, but it's broken for you? I'm not sure it's your site that's broken, it may be your computer/browser, have you tried turning off VPNs/Adblockers?

Comment: Yes, that URL works for me outside of the WP admin panel, too. So I'm not sure what would cause it to break inside the WP admin panel. I've thought about doing some kind of global code search inside WP Admin, but I'm not sure that function is available for the entire site. The Adblocker is off, so that's not it. Just very strange!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it only occurred after changing the domain for my site.  Even new users's get broken profile photos.

Chrome Dev tools says: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT  The gravatar url works.

Request URL:
https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/caa7f7ac741d667181928dddf7cf2f69?s=64&d=identicon&r=g
**Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin**